# Serverless solution for long running query on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, amazon-aurora

I have a use case where i need to get report by running a query.
This report needs to be generated from two database, so basically two report and then both i have to sent in an email.

This report generation should be scheduled once in every day.

Running query to get report will take more than 15 minutes to 25 minutes  not more than that and size of the report will not be ore than 5 MB.

One database in Mysql Aurora in AWS and other one is On-prem Oracle.

I need to run both query from AWS but i am looking for something serverless solution.

Lambda will not work because of 15 minutes limitation.

What else we can use to solve this without any EC2 solution?

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look over AWS Glue Jobs, which should be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Glue python shell job`, this is serverless and you pay for what you use only.

Also there is no need to provision any resources as this is managed by aws and can be considered as extended lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so why cant we create many lambda and limit your query to write into different files .
In that way you can make sure that query/one lambda is not taking more than 15 minutes .

Is it mandatory to have report only if one file ?
If not then it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS SSM Automation with steps. You can find details in the following [Creating an Automation document that runs scripts (command line)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-document-script-commandline.html)